# Segmentation fault when printing contents of a multidimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, segmentation-fault

I'm running the following C program and getting `Segmentation fault: 11`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 2

void print_array(double **arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("%f\n", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double mat[SIZE][SIZE] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    print_array((double **) mat, SIZE);
}
```

Could someone explain why this might be happening? I don't believe that I need to dynamically allocate memory for `mat`, since I'm passing it into `print_array` ***within*** the `main()` function.

When changing the function signature of `print_array()` to

```
void print_array(int size, double arr[size][size])
```

the problem goes away.

Still curious though... Why do I get the segmentation fault when casting `mat` as `double **` and passing it into `print_array()`? At the end of the day, `double arr[2][2]` and `double **arr` with size 2 are the same thing, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting undefined behavior since you're lying to the compiler about what your memory contains.

The in-memory format of `mat` is not the same as `(double **)`. The former is a compact square of `double`s, the latter is a pointer to a pointer. These are not the same.

You can represent a 2D as an array of row (or column, if you feel like it) pointers, which makes double indexing work. But that isn't the same thing as indexing into an actual array.

**UPDATE**: I'm not sure if it's possible to come up with a function signature for a function that can access either an actual compact array, or one represented through pointers ... My suggestion would be to keep it simple and write two different functions for these different requirements:

```
void print_matrix_compact(const double *el0, size_t size);
void print_matrix_indirect(const double **mtx, size_t size);
```

Here `el0` is a pointer to element 0 of an actual ("compact") array, while `mtx` is a pointer to an array of pointers for the one stored as an array of arrays. In both cases matrices are assumed to be square, with a size of `size`×`size` elements.

Comment: I understand now-- thank you for your answer. I am using this function to print the contents of square matrices stored on the stack within functions, as well as to print the contents of arrays initialized as `double **mat` using malloc calls. How could I go about using the same function for both? As I mentioned, changing the signature of the print function to accept `arr[size][size]` as well as a size parameter did the trick, but I feel as if I would get the same problem if trying to use that new function to print arrays stored as `double **`s, since they don't store the doubles contiguously.

Comment: The actual type of `arr`, when declared as `double arr[size][size]` and passed to a function  is `double[][size]`. The functions expects a `double*`. You call it correctly with: `print_matrix_compact(&arr[0][0], size);`

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same.

A `double[size][size]` is a contiguous block of memory containing `double`s where the compiler knows how to calculate the addresses out of the indices.

A `double **` is a pointer to a block of memory containing one or more pointers to blocks of `double`s.

By accessing the `double[size][size]` as `double **` you are interpreting your `double` values as pointers.